# Primefaces growl message from dialog external file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, growl

I have jsf page with TabView... Together 3 tabs. Tabs calls dialogs with some forms for creating elements. Dialogs are placed in external .xhtml page.
First tab is on "main" page (code placed below) and growl message called from validation bean shows well on the page. Second tab is calling growl message but from button placed on form from external file with dialogs... No errors occurs but the growl message didn't show at all.

My "main" view:

```
    <ui:composition>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="4000" />
        <h:form id="systemSettingsForm">

            <p:tabView id="ticketSettingsTab" rendered="true" widgetVar="tabViewVar">

                <p:tab id="tab0">
                    ...
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab1">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/tags/dialogs.xhtml" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Add" oncomplete="PF('addDialog').show()" update=":systemSettingsForm:ticketSettingsTab:addingDlg" />
                    ...
                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Dialogs view looks like (nothing special as I think...):

```
   <p:dialog id="addPositionDlg" header="Add position" widgetVar="addDialog">
        <h:panelGrid id="addingDlg" columns="3" > 
            <p:outputLabel value="Position name :"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="selectType" value="#{positionsTableView.positionType}" > 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one option" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{positionsTableView.types}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:outputLabel style="width:1px;"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Prefix :" />
            <p:inputText id="addPrefix" value="#{positionsTableView.newPosition.prefix}" />
            <pe:tooltip for="addPrefix" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur">...</pe:tooltip>
            //few simillar inputs, not even validated
            <center>
                <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{positionsTableView.addByPrefix}" ajax="true"
                    update=":systemSettingsForm:ticketSettingsTab:mappingTable" oncomplete="PF('addDialog').hide();"/>          
            </center>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

Growl message is added in actionListener invoked by command button in dialog form (#{positionsTableView.addByPrefix}) and this bean is in the same package as previous one (this working) and message is added in the same manner, which is:

```
    public static void addMessage(String title, String message) {
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(title,  message));
    }
```

Both beans calling messages are session-scoped.

I have searched here and tried to google solutions but none was successful...
Please help.

MY SOLUTION:

At command button which invokes the message to be displayed on growl element I have updated whole tabView menu and it works.Maybe it's not the best solution, but updating growl id causes an error (it was not visible from dialog file).

Comment: Did u try to put the growl inside the form? did u try to put the growl id in the "update" ?

Comment: Are you implying that it works fine when you replace the `<ui:include>` by its entire content? Please, come up with a true MCVE instead of copypasting parts of real code full of distracting noise. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. At least, that closing `</h:body>` in the include file doesn't look good.

Comment: The longer I'm working, the most this page becoming more and more useless. Forget about getting the answer when you have really not common problem (with other google is much better solution).
Thanks BalusC, everyone can paste whole code (it would be at least 400 lines and I wanted to avoid pasting it cause I wouldnt like to read such code).

Comment: BalusC did **not** ask about full code,he asked about an mcve. Did you read those links? And what page is not useful? StackOverflow?

Comment: Helpfulness of answer depends on helpfulness of the question to the answerer. Those links explain how to create the most helpful question (and thus exponentially increase the chance in getting a helpful answer).

Comment: Thank You Yassine_Hell, your comment gave me an idea what should cause the problem... It was actually refreshing, but not growl but tabView.

I have refreshed tabView form and it worked!